# Is there a classification of infinite simple groups?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, simple-groups

The classification of finite simple groups is known to be very very long. But I was wondering: is there somehow a classification of the infinite simple groups, or at least a beginning of a classification?

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/843251/examples-of-infinite-simple-groups) are a few examples. Such a classification might appear far more difficult than the one for finite simple groups, but sometimes the infinite case is easier, as shown [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886600). For instance, the classification of algebraically closed fields of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ is just based on the characteristic, if I'm not mistaken.

Any comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: ZOMG I'm famous !

Comment: @Alphonse: Just a remark. There is a total classification of algebraically closed fields. They depend (up to isomorphism) only on transcendence degree and characteristic.

Comment: As far as I can tell, a classification of any kind is hopeless even for simple finitely generated groups.

Comment: I agree with @studiosus, but you might be interested in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476972/theorems-with-the-greatest-impact-on-group-theory-as-a-whole/479440#479440) which discusses a program to attempt to classify certain kinds of simple groups with some sort of finiteness condition. I don't know if that program is hopeless

Comment: @PaulPlummer: Yes, I have heard about this program. I have no idea how realistic it is (I know very little about logic) but given the list of people working on it and progress that they have made, I would never consider it as hopeless. The class of groups of finite Morley rank is essentially disjoint from finitely generated groups (apart from finite groups).